# How to pass alert trough route.js in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes

I've made a function in order to confirm a mail adress.
I would like to show a toaster alert when the user confirm is mail.
Howwver, i'm stuck in the route/users/confirmation.js and i dont know how to pass it trough a component from there.

```
import ApplicationRoute from '../../routes/application';
import Ember from 'ember';
import ENV from "../../config/environment";

export default ApplicationRoute.extend({
  beforeModel(params) {
    const confirmationToken = params.queryParams.confirmation_token;

    // Call backend with confirmation token
    Ember.$.ajax({
      url: ENV.API_HOST + '/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=' + confirmationToken,
      type: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'x-api-key': ENV.APP.api_key
      }
    this.transitionTo('app');

    return {};
  }
});
```

I've been thinking of passing params trough the transitionTo but it appear to be a little bit unsuited..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i've found a package who do the work for me https://github.com/poteto/ember-cli-flash
And i just have to add the line below to my confirmation.js

```
 flashMessages: Ember.inject.service(),
Ember.get(this, 'flashMessages').success('Congratulations ! You\'ve just confirm your email address !');
```

and call it in a component

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for your ajax call to be resolved. Then you can `transitionTo` your `app`-route and provide a query param which contains a success or error flag. Something like this should work:

```
model(params, transition) {
  const confirmationToken = transition.queryParams.confirmation_token;

  // Call backend with confirmation token
  return Ember.$.ajax({
    url: ENV.API_HOST + '/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=' + confirmationToken,
    type: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'x-api-key': ENV.APP.api_key
    }
  });
},

afterModel(response) {
  this.transitionTo('app', { queryParams: { success: response.success }});
}
```

In your `app`-route you can use the queryParam success and pass it into a component to show your toast. Nice side-effect: you can use your `confirmation`-route for a loading screen.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. it appears that if the users relaod the page he will fall again on the notification this its in the url because of transitionTo